# Google Sheets API get an array of data in DataTable from a range of cells

Tags: vb.net

There is a Google Sheets. Sample data:

21; 5; Empty; Empty; 4; 62;
Empty; 74; 1; 32; 64; 8;
9; Empty; Empty; Empty; Empty; Empty

Opened a Google spreadsheet through the Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.
I am using code:

```
Public ss As Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService
 
Dim orange As String = oSheet.Properties.Title & "!А1:К100"
Dim requestSh As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = ss.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(file.Id, orange)
Dim response = requestSh.Execute()
Dim values As IList(Of IList(Of Object)) = response.Values
```

As a result, I received an array of data without empty cells. Example:
21; 5; 4; 62;
74; 1; 32; 64; 8;
9

I can't identify such data by columns. Reading each cell separately is long and inconvenient
How to get a data matrix with empty cells, like in a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Please [edit] the post to translate all of it, as bilingual posts are not allowed either. If you feel more comfortable writing in Russian, feel free to visit [ru.so].